# Why does Typescript constant of type interface convert null to a string "null"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below code which is setting up the initial state for a dataStore in an Angular2 app but the `INIT_STATE.token` is `"null"` and not `null`

```
export interface IAuthState{
  authenticated: boolean,
  token?: any
}

const INIT_STATE: IAuthState = {
  authenticated: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? true : false,
  token: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? localStorage.getItem('id_token') : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted I thought of a possible silly issue which was indeed the cause, some how `"null"` got stored in the localStorage instead of removing the item.